# selected options in a combobox in asp

Tags: listview, asp-classic, listboxitem

I'm working with asp classic (no .net) I have a list of users, and I'm stuck trying to 
  put a kind of label when the users (who are order by id_rol)change, for example if the
  user looks in the list the first option gets ("Todos")that means he can see All users,
  but if he looks 1 could see 10 users with the id_rol=1, if looks the 12 place of this
  list it shows a label call "Editor" and shows other 10 users, my problem is, that in the
  code I'm telling that if the option is 0 shows TODO, if is 1 shows DIRECTOR and the
  users below, if the selecction is 12 shows DIGITADOR and all user who are in that
  description, if the place in the list is 22 shows EDITOR and goes on,

[image]
  rigth now show that options in the 0,1,2 and 3 place but i need it in 0,1,12 and 22 place
  any help? please.
  here is my code:

```
function cb_usuarios(cod_usuario)
'response.write seccion&"<*------"
sql=" select * from usuarios where 1=1"
'sql=" select * from usuarios where 1=1 order by id_rol asc"
if Session("id_perfil") ="1" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(3,4)"
if Session("id_perfil") ="2" then sql = sql &" and id_rol=3"
if Session("id_perfil") ="3" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(3,4,7)"
if Session("id_perfil") ="4" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(1,7,6)"
if Session("id_perfil") ="6" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(7,4)"
'sql = sql &" order by nombre "
 sql = sql &" order by id_rol "

'if(id_rol=1)then
'response.write director
'else
'response.write('esto es una prueba')
'response.write sql
Set rsx = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsx.Open SQL, conexion, 3
%>

Usuarios<select name="usuarios" class="filtros">
<option selected value="0">TODOS</option>
<option selected value="1">DIRECTOR</option>
<option selected value="12">DIGITADOR</option>
<option selected value="22">EDITOR</option>

<%
while not rsx.eof
if ( trim(rsx("usuario")) = trim(cod_usuario)) then
sel="Selected"
else
sel=""
end if 
%>
<option select value="<%=rsx("usuario")%>" <%=sel%>><%=rsx("nombre")%></option>
<%
rsx.movenext
wend
rsx.close
%></select><%
end function
```

Comment: Confusing question, the poor english doesn't help.  But it almost looks like you should have a separate dropdown for your dynamic values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for select is...

```
<select>
    <option value="1">unos</option>
    <option selected value="2">duos</option>
```

there is not such a thing as: option ***select*** value.... that ***select*** is wrong html only selected is html

Answer (score 0):

this code made the trick:

[image]

```
function cb_usuarios(cod_usuario)
'response.write seccion&"<*------"


     sql=" select * from usuarios where 1=1"
    'sql=" select * from usuarios where 1=1 order by id_rol asc"


            if Session("id_perfil") ="1" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(3,4)"
            if Session("id_perfil") ="2" then sql = sql &" and id_rol=3"
    if Session("id_perfil") ="3" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(3,4,7)"
    if Session("id_perfil") ="4" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(1,7,6)"
    if Session("id_perfil") ="6" then sql = sql &" and id_rol in(7,4)"

        'sql = sql &" order by nombre "
     sql = sql &" order by id_rol "

    'if(id_rol=1)then
    'response.write director
    'else
    'response.write('esto es una prueba')






'   response.write sql
    Set rsx = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsx.Open SQL, conexion, 3
%>

Usuarios<select name="usuarios" class="filtros">

        <option selected value="0">TODOS</option>





    <%
    while not rsx.eof
        if ( trim(rsx("usuario")) = trim(cod_usuario)) then
            sel="Selected"
        else
            sel=""
        end if 
                    if ( trim(rsx("id")) =9) then
                     %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel%>>======DIRECTOR=======</option>
        <%
                      end if
                     if ( trim(rsx("id")) =47) then
                     %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel%
>>======DIGITADOR=======</option>
        <%
                      end if
                  if ( trim(rsx("id")) =37) then
                  %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel%>>=====EDITOR========</option>
        <%
        end if
        if ( trim(rsx("id")) =24) then
                  %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel%>>=====SUPERVISOR
JEFE========</option>
        <%
        end if
        if ( trim(rsx("id")) =41) then
                  %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel% 
 >>=====ADMINISTRADOR========</option>
        <%
        end if
        if ( trim(rsx("id")) =43) then
                  %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel%
 >>=====SUPERVISOR========</option>
        <%
        end if

        if ( trim(rsx("id")) =29) then
                  %>
        <option select value="0" <%=sel%
 >>=====CODIFICACION========</option>
        <%
        end if      %>
        <option select value="<%=rsx("usuario")%>" <%=sel%>><%=rsx
 ("nombre")%></option>
        <%
        rsx.movenext
    wend
    rsx.close
%></select><%
 end function
```